# no output, if I dont press +

Tags: c#, wpf

In this method, my programm just functions with +.
If I try to use -, * or / it will not give any answer.
Why is this happening?

```
public void istgleich_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int option1 = Convert.ToInt32(rechnung.Content);
    int option2 = Convert.ToInt32(rechnung_2.Content);

    int a = option2 + option1;
    int b = option1 - option2;
    int c = option2 * option1;
    int d = option1 / option2;

    Convert.ToString(a);
    Convert.ToString(b);
    Convert.ToString(c);
    Convert.ToString(d);

    if (rechnung_2.HasContent && rechnung_zeichen.Content.Equals("+"))
    {
         ergebnis.Content = a;
    }

    else if (rechnung_2.HasContent && rechnung_zeichen.Content.Equals("-"))
    {
         ergebnis.Content = b;
    }

    else if (rechnung_2.HasContent && rechnung_zeichen.Content.Equals("*"))
    {
         ergebnis.Content = c;
    }

    else if (rechnung_2.HasContent && rechnung_zeichen.Content.Equals(":"))
    {
         ergebnis.Content = d;
    }
}
```

And this is the only other time, i change the value of "rechnung_zeichen" in my code:

```
    public void plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                rechnung_zeichen.Content = "+";
            }
public void minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rechnung_zeichen.Content = "- ";
        }
public void geteilt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rechnung_zeichen.Content = ": ";
        }

        public void mal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rechnung_zeichen.Content = "* ";
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please follow this site's tagging guidelines and don't put tags in your question title.

Comment: Which type of control is rechnung, rechnung2, rechnung_zeichen and ergebnis?

Comment: If only the first condition "works" then likely the value of `rechnung_zeichen.Content` is always "+".
Du must schauen wie diese Control befüllt wird.
By the way you don't need the 4x Convert.ToString. Their returns go to nirvana, so you just should remove these 4 lines.

Comment: rechnung, rechnung2 and rechnung_zeichen are lables for outputing and showing the pressed numbers and operators for this calculator

Comment: @lidqy thank you for the tipp with "Convert.ToString".

Comment: Could you show the code that changes the value of "rechnung_zeichen.Content"? Since it is a Label control it cannot be changed by user input. So maybe the code that should change "rechnung_zeichen.Content" has still at little issue, so it always has a value of "+"...

Comment: Sorry @lidqy i'm new to stack overflow and don't know how to answer a question with a code example, so i put the code into my qustion.

Comment: Hi @hellworld. So we now found the reason why always "+" is chosen. 
Probably "plus" is a button(?) .
Then you need also other buttons for "-", "*", ":" and click-event-handlers that assign their "operator" to `rechnung_zeichen.Content`.
In `minus_click` for example you would have the line: 
`rechnung_zeichen.Content = "-";`
Same procdure in multiply_click etc

Comment: Hi again, so i already have these click-event-handlers ( you can see them in my updated Code above ). But it still dont't functions.

Comment: Hi again. In the other 3 you have a **whitespace** after the aritmetic operator. It's "* " not "*" and "- " not "-". Remove the 3 spaces and it'll work

Comment: yes now it works.

Comment: Nevermind, that's just how everybody starts. You learn by these little mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking against `"-"`, `"*"`, `":"` and yet set the values to `"- "`, `"* "`, `": "`.
So the checks against these values will always fail as the strings contain an extra space character.